# Showing a loading image when a function is being called

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to show a loading image whilst a javascript function runs. Its crunching a lot of numbers and on slower pc's it can take a few seconds to run.

I thought this would work

```
function myFunction(){;
    $('#loading').show();
    // The bit that takes ages to run
    $('#loading').hide();
}
```

However it doesn't seam to unhide the #loading div.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you returning from your function before hiding?

Comment: no nothing is returned, it adds data to a texbox with .innerhtml

Comment: Can't predict the problem from what you posted.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Are you replacing some textContent/innerHTML of an element? And in the bit that takes ages to run, does it call other functions? If so there might be something you could do with css and a background-image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Since JavaScript is single-threaded, it won't update the visibility of the loading image until after it's done, by which time you've already told it to hide again.

Additionally, even if it did work, an animated GIF would not play for the same reason, it would just appear frozen.

The optimal solution here is to use Web Workers, however these are quite advanced and only work in up-to-date browsers.

The next-best-thing would be to do something along these lines:

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#loading").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        // long code here
        $("#loading").hide();
    },1); // give it a moment to redraw
}
```